# find numbers in array that add up to a given number c++

Tags: c++, sum, boolean

I am writing this code that takes the input file and sorts all the integers from that file into an array. Then it takes the sum chosen by the user  and goes through all the combinations (one by one /professors orders/) to find a pair that equal the desired sum. some of the code is funky because we are required to use a C++03 compiler -sigh-. The program has no errors but when I run it it says

There were 1600 checks made to find the products of your desired sum and

the two numbers that add to your sum are 40 and 40
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

(the desired sum was not one that could have been found in the input file so it should have said " the program did not find any matches. try again. ")

The code is very messy and Im sorry but I have spent hours moving stuff around and adding new things or trying something new to try and make it work.

I have a feeling it is a problem with how I am declaring the boolean variables or maybe how I am passing them.

```
int x, i, n1, n2, pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0,accesses = 0;
bool fail = false;

int readSortedArray (int array[20], int count, istream& infile)
{   
count = 0;
while(infile >> array[count])
{
    count++;

}

return count;
}

int findproducts (int array[20], int& n1, int& n2, int count, int sum, int& accesses, bool fail, istream& infile)
{   
bool found = true;
while(found == true)
{
for( i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
pos1++;
n1 = array[i];
pos2 = 0;
for( x = 0; x < count; x++)
{
pos2++; accesses ++;
n2 = array[x]; 
if(sum == n1 + n2)
{
    found = false;
    fail = false;
}
if(sum != n1 + n2)
{
    fail = true;
}
}
}
}

return fail;
}

int main ()
{
 int array[20];
 int answer, sum, count = 0;

std::string input_filename;
ifstream infile;

cout << "Please enter name of the input file: ";
cin >> input_filename;
infile.open(input_filename.c_str());
if (!infile)
{
    cout << "Could not open input file one\n";
    return 0;
}

cout << "Please enter the prefered sum ";
cin >> sum;

count = readSortedArray(array, count, infile); 

fail = findproducts(array, n1, n2, count, sum, accesses, fail, infile);

cout << "There were " << accesses << " checks made to find the products of your desired sum and" << endl;

if(fail == true)
{
    cout << " the program did not find any matches. try again. ";
}
if(fail == false)
{
cout << endl << "the two numbers that add to your sum are " << n1 << " and " << n2 << endl << ". These were found in position " << pos1 << " and " << pos2;
}

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: It feels like the line setting fail to true could be executing in your for loop even after the sum was found. Try returning !found Also if you want to keep n1 and n2 the values that work, you better break out of both for loops, I think.

Comment: if(sum == n1 + n2)
{
    found = false;
    fail = false; return false;
}

Comment: if your sum is not found, the while loop will run forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I incorporated Karan S Warraich's comment about the bool type. I also removed the file parameter to findProducts. But the big issue was the while loop ran forever when it did not find anything. I got rid of it. Also, it was important to get out of the for before the good numbers were lost again and fail was reset. As you note, a number of code cleanups are possible (like found now does nothing, and fail need not be set within findproducts), but here is something that works

```
bool findproducts (int array[20], int& n1, int& n2, int count, int sum, int& accesses, bool fail)
{   
bool found = true;
for( i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    pos1++;
    n1 = array[i];
    pos2 = 0;
    for( x = 0; x < count; x++)

        {
        pos2++; accesses++;
        n2 = array[x]; 
        if(sum == n1 + n2)
        {
        found = false;
        fail = false;
        return false;
        }

        }
}

return true;
}
```

Comment: Also, I am not sure whether you are supposed to refer to the zeroth spot in the array as position 1 or 0. If the latter, your reporting is one off. Simpler, too, than making pos1 and pos2 work to keep pace would be within the if (sum == n1+n2) block just set pos1 to i and pos2 to x.

Comment: When I say it runs forever, that would be theoretically. Practically, that was probably what caused the segmentation fault.

Comment: I added your code to my program and it's definetly way better than the code I was working with but still didnt seem to fix the problem. Since the while variable was gone I took out the fail variable completely from my code. Then I added x = count and i = count to the if statement which got rid of the continous loop. Now the only problem seems to be that the bool variable is not returning. I asked a new question on that tho.

Answer (score 0):

In your findproduct function you are returning bool value while your function is of int type that is either make your function a bool return type or return 1 for true and 0 for false

Comment: Thank you great catch! unfortunately, still doesn't work. same output as before.

Comment: Whats the output though?

Comment: There were 1600 checks made to find the products of your desired sum and the two numbers that add to your sum are 40 and 40
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: it should say "There were 1600 checks made to find the products of your desired sum and the program did not find any matches. try again. "

Comment: One thing I would suggest to do is to put a cout command inside if (sum==n1+n2) and check where it is matching or have you already tried it?